# Why does Gmail show two different pictures for my profile, one of which is not me?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-contacts, profile, profile-picture

Recently, a strange thing occurred in my account when viewing it on my laptop computer. I have my normal profile picture that appears in the upper right hand corner of what I see when viewing my mail at `mail.google.com`. However, if I pick any email in my inbox and view that email, after the email content is a separator line and a box that reads `Click here to Reply or Forward` and to the left of the box that contains that text is another picture that is not my profile picture, but a picture of one of my contacts.

Why is this random contact picture appearing next to my reply-to line and how do I get my own photo to appear instead of this other person's in my contacts?

Is there some kind of corruption coming from my Android phone that is causing this?

I checked my Google+ account (which I don't really use) and didn't see any issue with my profile picture there. Is there some other place that is getting crossed wires with my Gmail profile?

I have confirmed that my email recipients see my correct profile picture, so I'm not sure if this random profile picture is showing up anywhere else as being me. I also see that if I go into my `sent` folder, each email I have sent shows this random profile picture as being me, the author of the emails I have sent.

I tried deleting the contact that has the erroneous picture showing up as me, deleting the contact from my phone and from my contacts at `contacts.gmail.com`. However, even after deleting that contact, I still see this extra picture as me that is really someone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a contact saved with your email address and the photo is saved there. Locate the contact and delete the photo and it will take the one from your Google profile automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The bug appears to be related to corruption between the gmail and hangouts profiles that are supposedly synchronized.  Updating the picture in hangouts fixed the issue, even though that is supposedly shared with gmail and updating in gmail left two versions.

Answer (score 3):

Remove and re-upload your profile photo from your Google Contacts page (https://contacts.google.com).

was looking like this
[image]

removed image and re-uploaded image here [image]

now looking like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug or any corruption in your smartphone. It's one of gmail features. Try opening your mails on a desktop browser and you will see the same result as in gmail of your smartphone.